# How to keep different configs i.e. CD and CMS in Tfs?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sitecore, sitecore8

Im trying keep different configs files for separate environment CD&CMS, is there any tools or option i can use ?

im using vs2013 with tfs.

Thanks

Comment: `CD` = "Content Delivery", `CMS` = "Content Management System" ?

Comment: Do you create different build packages for CD and CM or do you deploy the same one?

Comment: currently I havnt setup any packages yet, just tend to copy manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a directory structure where you keep the CM and CD files. Below is an example of the directory structure

---App_Config

-----Include

--------zConfig

-----------CM Config

-----------CD Config

Then you can create a build script which takes into consideration the Build Configuration (debug, release). From this, when you build your solution it will know which config to take.

I would suggest to define new Build Configuration to minimiythe risk of confusion. Example, create 1 for CM and 1 for CD

This is an example how my build script looks like in my solution

```
if %Configuration% EQU  DEBUG ( if exist %SolutionDir%..\..\Website\App_Config\Include\ABBs\UAT  RMDIR /S /Q  %SolutionDir%..\..\Website\App_Config\Include\ABBs\UAT  if exist %SolutionDir%..\..\Website\App_Config\Include\ABBs\PRODCluster1 RMDIR /S /Q  %SolutionDir%..\..\Website\App_Config\Include\ABBs\PRODCluster1 if exist %SolutionDir%..\..\Website\App_Config\Include\ABBs\PRODCluster2 RMDIR /S /Q  %SolutionDir%..\..\Website\App_Config\Include\ABBs\PRODCluster2 if exist %SolutionDir%..\..\Website\App_Config\Include\ABBs\PRODCluster3 RMDIR /S /Q  %SolutionDir%..\..\Website\App_Config\Include\ABBs\PRODCluster3 )
```

It will copy the config file from my solution to the path \Website\App_Config\Include\ABBs\PRODCluster1 if my Build Configuration is Debug

Comment: Will the build configuration look into app_config folder or does it only on web.config ?

Comment: If you already placed the config files in your solution, your build script needs to look into the app_config from the solution so that it can copy and paste it in the website app config folder. In the build script you will already specify whete to put the files. Either bin folder or app_config/include folder

Comment: I have added an example of my build script which copies the config files from my solution to the \Website\App_Config\Include\ABBs\PRODCluster1

Comment: is this in post build script ?

Comment: Yes, you add it in the post build event

Answer (score 4):

For regular .NET configurations you have the ability to add transform files based on build configurations.
You can also use [Slowcheetah](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) which has a similar idea for files that are not standard .net configurations. The idea is to have one build configuation with it's corresponding transformation configurations.
For example you configure on Visual Studio a build definition for CM and one for CD. With the transformation files you can have specific environment configurations based on the corresponding environment(configs for CM or CD).
For deployment you can configure whatever tool you are using which build configuration it should use. For example to deploy to a CD environment you should build using the CD configuration and so on.